# How to soften homemade butter

Tags: butter

I like to make homemade butter from cream using a churn, but it's super super stiff and I can't spread it on food without ripping it apart. Is there something I can add to make it softer?

I tried leaving it out in a butter try, but it starts to grow mold in a day or two.

Comment: Have you tried churning it with a bit of olive oil?

Comment: Sounds like you're somehow churning out too much water.  If you're not adding it already, a little salt should prevent mold for at least a little while.

Answer (score 4):

I make butter spreadable-from-the-fridge by adding grapeseed oil ([recipe here](http://toriavey.com/toris-kitchen/2013/04/homemade-spreadable-butter/) -- 1:1 ratio for very soft "butter") and blending in a food processor for a smooth consistency.

This is done after the butter is churned, or after leaving store-bought sticks to come to room temperature. Pretty much any oil *can* work for this, but a neutral-flavored oil will keep the mixture tasting like *butter*.

I don't recommend using this for anything besides buttering bread; changing the consistency in this way can affect baked goods.